# MLT Framework Target GPU

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mlt

I have a laptop with both an AMD iGPU and an AMD dedicated GPU and I'm using shotcut which apparently uses the MLT Framework.  It seems like shotcut is using the iGPU for HW acceleration based on encoding times.  I can specify a target device in ffmpeg using the "hwaccel_device" parameter and it appears that shotcut has an option for passing parameters to MLT.

Is there a parameter that I can pass to MLT in order to specify the target gpu for ffmpeg to use?  I guess I'm looking for the MLT equivalent to ffmpeg's "-hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD129"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: **Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/**. Please delete this.

Comment: Thanks to Dan over at Shotcut, we found an option called vaapi_device.  In my case, I've been using it to target a specific gpu with the following:
"vaapi_device=/dev/dri/renderD129"

I'm not sure I'm seeing the improvement that I expected in speed, but I suspect it's due to some of the additional processing happening or something else I'm missing.

Comment: It doesn't matter what mlt says. For the reasons stated above in bold, if this isn't a specific programming question, it doesn't belong here and you should delete this.

Answer (score 0):

The vaapi_device option may be helpful for others facing this issue.
example usage:

```
vaapi_device=/dev/dri/renderD129
```

Comment: The question is off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. [answer]